# How to increase the numwidth for a part in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, parts

I am using a Koma-Script Book and I would like to begin the part numbers from 2012. However, 4 digit part number entries are causing a problem in the tableofcontents. There is a hbox overfull and the last digit of 2012 is overlapping with the first one or two characters of the part heading. I am using the command `\tableofcontents` to generate the ToC.

What is a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package, you can redefine `\cftpartnumwidth`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftpartnumwidth{2cm}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{part}{2011}
\part{Test Part}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, not requiring additional packages is to redefine `\l@part` as defined in `scrbook.cls`; here's such a possible redefinition:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{2cm}% original value: 2em
    \if@tocleft
      \ifx\toc@l@number\@empty\else
        \setlength\@tempdima{0\toc@l@number}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \usekomafont{partentry}{#1\nobreak
        \usekomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\hfil\nobreak
          \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss#2}}}\par
      \ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
      \endgroup
      \penalty20010
      \else
          \penalty\@highpenalty
      \endgroup
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{part}{2011}
\part{Test Part}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, so tocloft is a package! I read it everywhere and thought it was some another toc method which I did not want to venture into. Let me check and I will get back to you.

Comment: Thank You. This works. I should probably wait sometime before accessing the answer though.

Comment: Note: Combination of `tocloft` with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended and results in a warning.

Answer (score 13):

With a KOMA-Script class there is no additional package needed. You can use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=2cm
]{part}
```

to change the space for the part number in TOC to `2cm`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=2cm
]{part}

\setcounter{part}{2011}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\part{Last part}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using KOMA-Script, you could have a look at the package `tocstyle`.

```
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
```

This requires extra compilation runs to calculate the widths of the TOC.

Comment: Note: `tocstyle` was an alpha package, that has been removed from the TeX distributions.