# Customized section name superposing summary words

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, sectioning, latex3, subsection

I have created a customized subsection name

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Parte \Alph{subsection}.}
```

But it is conflicting with the Table of Contents because "Parte" is too long, as below:
[image: Name of the customized subsection is superposing with name of section in the summary.]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Also relevant: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/277964)

Comment: Also related: [How to increase the numwidth for a part in ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63856/277964) (you would have to abstract from `part` to `subsection`)

Comment: If non of the questions above help you to find a solution, please don't show only a code snippet, but a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be used to reproduce the problem and what you've tried to solve it.